# Update Array State on React using Hooks replaces instead of concat

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this hook:

```
const [pastChat, setPastChat] = useState([]);
```

I'm updating it with a function that it's called when the user presses a button:

```
const nextAction = (step) => {
    //...do a bunch of things...
    let nextInLine = [array with an object];
    setPastChat(pastChat.concat(nextInLine));
}
```

This code works just fine, but when I try to run this `setPastChat()` in a loop (while or for loop) it just replaces the last item instead of `concat()` it. I'm using concat because `push()` does not work as well.
So I have something like this:

```
const nextActionLoop = (step) => {
    //...do a bunch of things...
    let nextInLine = [array with an object];
    let index = 0;
    while(index < 5) {
        //...change nextInLine's object;
        setPastChat(pastChat.concat(nextInLine));
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I tried to log `pastState` and even in the function that works the state appears not the be updated after `setPastChat(pastChat.concat(nextInLine));`. It does update my view correctly, but it might do this a while after. I have no idea and I'd like to know how can I just concat new items in the while loop, please.

I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly enqueue multiple state updates. The issue is that all the queued updates use *the same* `pastChat` state value from the current render cycle, so each update overwrites the previous one and the last update is the one you see.

```
const nextActionLoop = (step) => {
    //...do a bunch of things...
    let nextInLine = [array with an object];
    let index = 0;
    while(index < 5) {
        //...change nextInLine's object;
        setPastChat(pastChat => pastChat.concat(nextInLine));
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

This will use the previous state and compute the next state value.

Here's a demo of mine that demonstrates the difference between a regular update and a functional update, and why the functional update works for multiple enqueued updates.

[image: Edit react - regular and functional state updates]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the process time in your loop, but if it's not slow and sync, you should first concat all your `pastChat` and then update the state:

```js
const nextActionLoop = (step) => {
    //...do a bunch of things...
    const iterations = 5;
    const newPastChat = Array(iterations).fill().map((_, i) => {
      const nextInLine = {...};

      return nextInLine;
    });

    setPastChat(newPastChat);
}
```

btw you're free of mutations, only functional code ;)